# How to reverse an array of numbers in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] xxx={1,3,5,7,9};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(krakin(xxx)));
}

public static int[] krakin(int[]x) {
    for(int i=x.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        int[]dev=new int[x.length-1];
        dev[i]=x[i];

    }
    return dev[i];
}
```

I'm writing a method in java that reverses the order of the passed array.
I'm getting an error saying `void` is not allowed in my `main` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] xxx={1,3,5,7,9};
    System.out.println(krakin(xxx));  
}
  
public static void krakin(int[]x){
    for(int i=x.length-1;i>=0;i--){     
  
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please do not use JavaScript snippets for anything other than JavaScript.

Comment: boris come on help me man. your active on this, calling people out . just teach me bro i really need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With additional libraries it can be done within one line.
If we consider pure Java then I would write like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] xxx = {1,3,5,7,9} ;
    int[] reversed = reverseWithStream(xxx);
    int[] reversed2 = reverseWithTempArray(xxx);

    Arrays.stream(reversed).forEach(System.out::println);
    Arrays.stream(reversed2).forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static int[] reverseWithStream(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                .boxed()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                .mapToInt(value -> value)
                .toArray();
}

private static int[] reverseWithTempArray(int[] sourceArray) {
    int[] tempArray = new int[sourceArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        tempArray[i] = sourceArray[sourceArray.length - 1 - i];
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

One of the biggest benefits of this one is the fact that the previously created array is not affected.
In case of:

java.util.Arrays#sort(int[])

Or apache commons methods, the previously created array is affected.

Comment: can you do it using a temporary array? this is to advanced im in the first java class . I have a exam monday

Comment: my teacher is no help and everyone here is just fighting with each other

Comment: Another awful usage of the `Stream` API. This takes an operation that should be `O(n)` and makes it `O(n lg n)`. Really, if you do not know how to use the new API don't post answers using it. Especially not to beginners why don't know just how awful this code is.

Comment: Sure. Added solution with arrays.

Comment: why did you use -1?

Comment: Since the first index of the array element is 0
it basically means that the array like this will have the following indexes:
{1,3,5,7,9}
 0 1 2 3 4
However, the length property shows the number of the elements and not the indexes. For this array it will be - 5. Since there is no element with index 5. We need to -1 to get them synchronized at some point.

Comment: wow man thanks, your the best! feel free not to answer this question but i was also wondering how do you know what to do with arrays? whats your thinking like? since im new, my brain just freezes up and I feel so lost. how do you do it

Comment: np. 
That was too long ago. Probably University. ;)
Then just solving similar tasks while working.

Answer (score 3):

Your `krakin` method has a `void` return type, which means it returns nothing. Therefore you can't pass it as an argument to `System.out.println`.

You can change it, for example, to return an int array:

```
public static int[] krakin(int[]x){

    int[] rev = new int[x.length];
    ...
    return rev;
}
```

Then you could print it in your main:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(krakin(xxx)));
```

Comment: The array could also be reversed in place, then `void` would make sense.

Comment: could you please include the complete code? thanks

Comment: @BoristheSpider In that case you could still return the same array, to allow statements such as `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(krakin(xxx)))` to work.

Comment: @sefasefsfeasefa I explained the error you got and how to fix it. I didn't write the actual logic for reversing the array, since I thought you should try it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, one could - but it makes the code semantically horrible. I like to stick to `void` if the argument is mutated and something if not. That way you don't get too many nasty surprises...

Comment: ok i posted what i thought would be right. i just dont understand why its not working now. and instead of using an int[] array as a return method is there a way to keep it as void?

Comment: boris can you help please

Comment: @BoristheSpider In that case, I guess you don't like the JDK's `Collection`'s `toArray(T[] a)` :)

Comment: There's lots of JDK methods I don't like! (sure you have some too...) That one is especially nasty because people pass in zero-length arrays to indicate type - yey, reified generics!

Comment: @sefasefsfeasefa First of all, the reversed array should be allocated before the loop (not inside it) and have the same length as the original array. Second of all, you are not reversing anything if the i'th element of the input array becomes the i'th element of the output array.

Comment: can you guys stop chirping each other and someone help me :(

Comment: eran i have a exam on monday, im trying to study. please help. the way you did made it harder for me. can you use void

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int [100];
    int j = numbers.length ;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
        numbers [i] = numbers [i] + j ;
        j = j - 1 ;
        System.out.println(numbers [i]);
    }
```